# Is this exercise of probabilities on dice correct?

Tags: probability, dice

The excercise is:

```
The problem says:

We have a dice
It's numbered from 1 to 6
We roll it two times and each time we record the number we get
The first roll/number we record is "a"

and the second is "b"
The question says: Calculate the probability of each one of these:
A) "The two numbers a and b apply the equation: b = 2a + 1"
B) "a and b apply: |a - b | < 1"
C) "a and b apply: |a - b| > 5"
```

Here is how I solved it:

```
P(A) = 2 / 36

P(B) = 1

P(C) = 0
```

Is it correct? Please tell me with justification.

Comment: Why would $P(B)=1$?  Are you suggesting that $|a-b|<1$ is always true?

Comment: If the difference between the numbers on the first die and second die is strictly less than $1$, it follows that the numbers on the two dice must have been equal.  What is the probability that $a=b$?  What is the probability that you roll two dice and they show the same number?

Comment: @lulu I mean, isn't it? I divided the absolute value into two inequalities: a - b < 1 and b - a < 1, and by uniting them both (Let's call them a'Ub') we find them equal to 1. Please correct me.

Comment: Well, let's try some values.  Say $a=1, b=2$.  Then $|a-b|=1$, no?

Comment: You don't combine them with a union here... you combine them with an intersection...

Comment: @JMoravitz Can you explain why please? I mean, when we get rid of the absolute value, we get two inequalities, right? Then we say (a - b < 1) OR (b - a < 1), "OR" means union...right?

Comment: Then we say (a - b < 1) **AND** (b - a < 1).  As lulu suggested... take a look at a specific example.  $|5-2|<1$ is false since $|5-2|$ which is equal to $+3$ is not less than $1$.  This is *despite* you having that $2-5<1$ happens to be true.

Comment: Recall that $|x|$ is only ever equal to a single value at a time.  $|x|$ is equal to $x$ in the event that $x$ was positive while $|x|$ is equal instead to $-x$ in the event that $x$ was negative... so saying something like $|x|=3$, yes that means that if we want to find what $x$ makes that true that we have $x=3$ or $x=-3$, but it is the case that given a specific value of $x$, then $|x|$ is equal to a single result in the end... not multiple simultaneously.  If it so happened that $x$ was equal to $3$ then we have that $|x|=3$... not that $|x|$ is $3$ or $-3$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Then what I do now? How do I intersect them? I have been thinking that that I apply P(A'x-A') = P(A') + P(-A') - P(A' U -A') but I have to calculate P(A') now and how I exactly do that? Btw, -A' means A bar since it's the opposite of A' when you get rid of absolute value.

Comment: @JMoravitz Wait, if I intersect them, doesn't that mean that I will find the probability = 0 since they are inexculsive and the opposite of each other? I'm so so confused right now.

Comment: @lulu Then how do I solve it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104277/discussion-between-technoknight-and-jmoravitz).

Comment: There's no need to think about unions or intersections.  For integers, $m,n$ we have $|m-n|<1\iff m=n$.  That is to say, there aren't any distinct integers that are nearer than $1$ from each other.

Comment: @lulu I found P(B) = 1 / 6, since the dice records could be (1,1) or (2,2) or (3,3) or (4,4) or (5,5) or (6,6) is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the help! And thank you for everyone who helped me too!